# Google Bot adding Robots.txt to end of the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, robots.txt, googlebot

Why does Google Bot keep adding robots.txt to the end of urls on an external site that is referencing a url on mine?

```
System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'documentsrobots.txt' was not found on controller 'Tournaments.Controllers.EventController'.

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```